# How to inject a mocked dbcontext in a service layer of a .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am currently writing unit tests and I am having the following problem:

I am supposed to write tests for the Service Layer. The service layer consists of different kind of Services, all of which implement the `ServiceBase` class. The main idea of the service base is expressed in the following logic

```
protected void GetContext(Action<DataContext> action)
{
    GetContext(action, DataContextOptions.Default);
}

protected void GetContextAutoSave(Action<DataContext> action)
{
    GetContext(action, DataContextOptions.AutoSave);
}

private static void GetContext(Action<DataContext> action, DataContextOptions options)
{
    using (var context = new DataContext(options))
    {
        action(context);
    }
}
```

So whenever an interaction with the db is needed, the following logic is applied in the services:

```
GetContext(dataContext =>
{
    perform some logic on the dataContext;
});
```

The `DataContext` class itself implements a base class which has constructor for setting up the `DbContext`. So this is how the application interacts with the db. As for the unit testing part I have decided to go with `MOQ` and I am pleased with its capabilities. I was able to fake the `DbContext` but now I am wondering how to inject it in the hierarchy of the program so that I can test the logic from the services with it. A more specific question would be which class from the above stated {`ServiceBase`,`DataContext`,`DataContextBase`}, has to mocked so that when I call the `GetContext` method I end up with a fake `DbContext`? As for the architecture of the logic for interaction with the db, I am open for any recommendations. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: Why not inherit from DataContext (e.g. MyDataContext), and create an interface (IMyDataContext) which has the properties and methods of the DataContext that you might want to test. Then you would want to inject a IMyDataContext into Service rather than creating it in your "GetContext" method. In that way you can mock IDataContext interface instead of the DataContext class.

Comment: injecting a DataContext in the constructor is a solution for testing purposes but according to me is introducing additional complexity in the service layer as each service has to create its own DataContext

Comment: I agree with @rashleighp. I have implemented [a solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1081815/Mocking-EF-DbContext) with using adapters. ıf you use DI container you can share dbcontext you don't have to extra implemantation on service layer. plus your servicelayer will be uncoupled with DbContext.